# help to identify this possibly compressed data header or format

Tags: decryption

So I'm trying to request data from a server and I've been able to connect the server and send commands to request data. I'm not sure of the command format itself i just used what i captured in wireshark and the server response with the same data that was also captured in wireshark. The problem is I cannot discern any format from the data. All received data seems to have a similar header like
b1cb74000c0130000100eb0f or b1cb74000c0130000200b50f. I thought it was a compression header but no decompression or inflate functions work. The data is stock data and in this case is tick data. It should contain min,hour,price,volume and buy/sell. I'll include one full received data below. Any ideas on if it is in fact compressed or another way i could approach it is appreciated.

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

Answer (score 2):

From just a bunch of data, that doesn't have any ovbious structure, it's impossible to tell.

This doesn't look like a standard encoding. For standard encodings, feeding google the hex codes of the first few bytes typcially gives you some results, and so does the linux `file` command, but this is not the case here. Try googling for `1f 8b` or `42 5a` to find `gzip` resp. `bzip2` quickly.

Unless you disassemble the executable file that processes this data, and checks how it reads the data (and possibly decrypts or converts it before actually reading it), it's quite probable you won't be able to find out anything.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be encrypted. You can see here the progression of characters `A` through `Z`: https://i.imgur.com/7a8jTOx.png

Comment: It's a list of 3 numbers per line (so not literally "min,hour,price,volume and buy/sell"). Each number is one byte if MSB not set, or `(b1 & 7Fh)+(b2<<7)` if the MSB is set. You can see one of the columns increasing (well, mostly). This data starts at pos. 14h. (The first column jumps *suspiciously* from 7Dh to C1h - perhaps it's a signed number and the sign itself takes another bit.)